# Known sizes at compile time of variadic arrays

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to deduce each array size at compile time, but I do not like the way which I came up with.

```
template <std::size_t Length>
struct __helper
{
    __helper(const char (&_sName)[Length])
    {
        memcpy(m_sName, _sName, Length);
    }

    char m_sName[Length];
};

template <std::size_t... Lengths>
static void foo(__helper<Lengths>... _namespaces)
{
}
```

I want to just pass text without **__helper** like *foo("test", "test2")* instead of *foo(__helper("test"), __helper("test2"))*. Is there any way to do this as I want?

Comment: Can't you do `sizeof(Lengths...)`?

Comment: But how I pass arrays to the function?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__helper`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax to take variadic C array is:

```
template <std::size_t... Ns>
static void foo(char (&...args)[Ns])
{
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried everything but not this...